# R & Python are showing two different result for a same problem. What is the reason behind it?

Tags: python, r

I am trying to get same result of this specific matrix, but they are returning slightly different result.
Here is the image of example code:
[image]

Comment: R is treating the computation as integer type, Python as float

Comment: @GustavRasmussen Not necessarily, in R `class(B[1,1])` returns `"numeric"` but `det(B)` is 8. Note: the matrix was created with  `B <- diag(c(1,2,4))`. I dupe hammered without checking.

Comment: If you just need the same result in Python as in r, you could use math.ceil: `det = math.ceil(np.linalg.det(x)) `

Comment: They're both calling LAPACK's `dgetrf` and `sprintf("%0.17f", det(diag(c(1, 2, 4))))` in R shows `"7.99999999999999822"`... This seems to be just a case of differences in how they **display** the answer, not differences in what they answer **is**. Of course, the easy to see true value of the answer is 8, but, you know, [floating point arithmetic / representation of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/8386140) and all...

Comment: If you use `identical(det(B), 8L)` you will get `FALSE` for result. Its just prinitng configuration. If you write `1.9999999` in console you will get `2` as output in console. I think that default parameter is `6` for decimal points (if you write `1.999999` you will get `1.999999`).

Answer (score 1):

In the `numpy` source code of the [`linag` module](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py) can be read:

> This module is a lite version of the linalg.py module in SciPy which
> contains high-level Python interface to the LAPACK library.

In the [`numpy` documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html#numpy.linalg.det) we find:

> The determinant is computed via LU factorization using the LAPACK routine z/dgetrf.

Also, in the [`scipy` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.det.html#scipy.linalg.det) we find:

> The determinant is computed via LU factorization, LAPACK routine z/dgetrf.

However, checking the [`numpy` source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L2105-L2161) and [`scipy` source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.5.0/scipy/linalg/basic.py#L986-L1041) can be seen that the `det` functions are not calculated in the same way. `scipy` returns the desired output:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.linalg.det(B)
8.0
```